# How to fix a 'SystemStackError: stack level too deep' error with a large amount of ActiveRecord conditions

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord query which iteratively adds or conditions to a search:

```
places.each do |place|
  people = people.or(People.within_radius_of(place.latitude, place.longitude, place.radius).select(:id))
end

scope :within_radius_of, ->(lat = nil, lon = nil, radius = 100_000) {
  where(earth_box(lat, lon, radius)).where(earth_distance_less_than(lat, lon, radius)) if lat.present? && lon.present?
}
```

`earth_box` and `earth_distance_less_than` are just functions to generate postgresql sql for `earth_box` and `earth_distance` queries.

This works without issue with our original max target of 100 places, but 600 places were added to a search and I get the stack level too deep issue.

What are the implications of increasing the stack size?  Default is 1MB, for example what issues might occur if I set it to 8MB or more?

Can this query be rewritten to avoid the error?

Comment: do you want to support that many places?  that seems really high unless a machine is asking for it?

Comment: Have you tried `places.find_each` instead of `places.each` yet? Good article here: https://rubyinrails.com/2017/11/16/use-find-each-instead-of-all-each-in-rails/ Also, what else are you doing with all this (e.g. is this in a view)

Comment: How does `within_radius_of` look like? How is `people` defined? Are you really still using Rails 3?

Comment: @Anthony yes I need to support this in some way for the business requirements

Comment: @spickermann added `within_radius_of` scope.  On Rails 5.0.7.1

Comment: @JayDorsey I don't believe this is a memory issue which `find_each` would fix, but will try that.  I don't use this in the view; after the query new records are created for each person that matches any of the places.

Comment: Increasing your stack size is almost certainly not the right answer. You can probably construct the SQL using a custom method. What does the SQL look like if you are working with, say, three places?

Comment: @moveson  what implications are there to increasing the stack size?  I have seen others with similar issues do this to fix it.

Comment: @riley The problem with solving this problem by increasing stack size is that you will have the same problem again when you increase the number of places again. There is a simple way to construct the required SQL without using a recursive method. I'll help you do that if you'll show me what the current SQL query looks like on a small scale, with just two or three places.

Comment: @moveson yes that would be an issue, however this is admin entered data and we will never go above the current amount.  If you can suggest a way to break down the query it would probably be a better solution.  You can see the current query in the details, it is using arel to `or` multiple queries of `where(earth_box(lat, lon, radius)).where(earth_distance_less_than(lat, lon, radius))` which just generate postgresql `earth_box` and `earth_distance` queries.

Comment: `find_each` did not fix the issue.  Setting the stack size to 4mb does fix it, although probably not optimal

Comment: @riley I agree setting the stack larger is not optimal. I can see the ActiveRecord query in your question; no need to repeat it. I'm asking you to put up the raw SQL that is generated by your ActiveRecord query. If you check your server logs you'll see it there. Of course the SQL will be very long if you show what is produced by 600 recursions, so please set number of places to 2 or 3, run a query, check the server logs, find the SQL, and copy/paste it into your question.